# Integration practice problem

Tags: integration

I'm having problem while solving this indefinite integration , this is just a practice problem. I've exam coming soon. And I stuck at this problem

Integration of $$\int\frac{e^{3x}+e^{5x}}{e^x+e^{-7x}} dx$$

I don't know how to use latex.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange. [Here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) is a MathJax tutorial

Comment: @user702057 It is not a bad practice to at least browse through the FAQ of a site when you join. In this case, it would have directed you to [this](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/107/faq-for-math-stackexchange/117#117)

Comment: Thank you. I'm going to check the FAQ section

Comment: Check [this](https://oeis.org/wiki/List_of_LaTeX_mathematical_symbols) for collection of all symbols.

Comment: the web tool http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html is quite handy for symbols.

Answer (score 2):

It is $${t}^{4}+{t}^{2}-{\frac {{t}^{2} \left( {t}^{2}+1 \right) }{{t}^{8}+1}}$$ with $e^x=t$ so it is not so hard to find this integral.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the substitution $u=e^x$. Then
$$dx=\frac{du}{u}$$
And you get a rational function to integrate

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

You want to compute $$I=\int\frac{e^{3 x}+e^{5 x}}{e^x+e^{-7 x}}\,dx$$ Let $x=\log(t)$ to end with
$$I=\int \frac{t^{11}+t^9}{t^8+1}\,dt=\int \left(t^3+t-\frac{t^3+t}{t^8+1}\right)\,dt$$

Now, take into account that
$$t^8+1=\left(t^4-\sqrt{2} t^2+1\right) \left(t^4+\sqrt{2} t^2+1\right)$$ Continue with partial fraction decomposition